# Android: Images uploaded to firebase with -90 rotation

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage, android-bitmap

I am using Samsung A52 to take some images with camera not my firebase app and save them, after that i would upload these images to firebase, iam compressing them before upload .

now after images were uploaded i checked and found that they are `-90` rotated, not all images rotated , some were rotated and some weren't;

any idea?

or is there any possibly to detect while loading images from firebase if it rotated to retotate is to `90` ?

function to upload images after getting them from gallery.

```
for (uploadCount  = 0; uploadCount < ImageList.size(); uploadCount++) {
    String imagePath = productRef.child(UID).child("images").push().getKey();

    Uri IndividualImage = ImageList.get(uploadCount);
    assert imagePath != null;
    StorageReference ImageName = productImagesRef.child(UID).child(imagePath);
   

    //Compress Images
    Bitmap bmp = null;
    try {
        bmp = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), IndividualImage);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    assert bmp != null;
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 25, baos);
    byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();
    //End of compressing

    //start on uploading compressed
    ImageName.putBytes(data).addOnSuccessListener(taskSnapshot -> ImageName.getDownloadUrl()
            .addOnSuccessListener(uri -> {
                String url = String.valueOf(uri);
                StoreLink(url, imagePath);
            })).addOnProgressListener(snapshot1 -> {
        double progress = (100.0* snapshot1.getBytesTransferred()/snapshot1.getTotalByteCount());
        loadingDialog.setMessage("صورة رقم " + (count+ 1) + "  -->>   " +(int) progress + "%");
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So i self Solved it and this was my solution:

i added a rotate button to the layout of `recyclerView item(Adapter)`, and then created an empty ArrayList to store the value or rotation degree.

i passed the arraylist to adapter which has the rotate button, now when user click on rotate a value of `90f` would be saved to arraylist with the position like this:

```
imageRotation.set(holder.getAdapterPosition(), "90f");
```

since arrayList can take `(index, value)`

Note: if there isn't an exiting value for the Arralist position and you skipped the position to change rotation for other item, it would crash.
and to solve this i made a for loop to populate the Arratlist with `0f` as a rotatiion degree.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= imageUriList.size(); i++) {
            imageRotation.add(i,"0f");
        }
```

then when user click on rotate, it would update the position value:

```
imageRotation.set(holder.getAdapterPosition(), "90f");
```

and onActivityResult of the Upload Activity:

i used this:

```
if (requestCode == LAUNCH_SECOND_ACTIVITY) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                assert data != null;
                imageRotationArray = data.getStringArrayListExtra("imageRotationArray");
            }
        }
```

and before the Compress image function:

// create new matrix

```
                Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                // setup rotation degree
                matrix.postRotate(Float.parseFloat(imageRotationArray.get(countRotateImage)));
                bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight(), matrix, true);
                countRotateImage++;
```